# how to Scroll only the Content of a mat-tab

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material2

[image: Image Description]

1) I have a mat-toolbar (fixed size: min-width:64px),

2) below the mat-toolbar, I have a Mat-Tab group,

3) some Tab contents are long, so I need a scrollbar only inside the tab.

4) However, the **Last lines of the Scrollable content are clipped** and not visible.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcvgxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div fxFill style="overflow:hidden !important">

<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="min-height:64px !important">
    <button mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon>Toolbar</mat-icon>
</button>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-tab-group fxFill>

<!-- need this tab content to fill -->
    <mat-tab label="Short-1">
        <div fxFill fxLayout="column" style="background-color:lightblue;">
            <p>Short Content 1</p>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>

<!-- need this to scroll but last few lines are clipped-->
    <mat-tab label="Long">
        <div fxFill fxLayout="column" style="overflow:auto;background-color:yellow;">
    <div >
              <p *ngFor="let line of lines">{{line}}</p>
    </div>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>

<!-- need this tab content to fill -->
<mat-tab label="Short-2">
        <div fxFill fxLayout="column" style="background-color:lightgreen;">
            <p>Short Content 2</p>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>


</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your toolbar has min-height: 64px !important;, so, on your tab please change:

min-height: 100%;
with
min-height: calc(100% - 64px);

Comment: Got it !... Thank you.!!

Answer (score 2):

It's working.!

> Thanks to **@Liviu Nita**

[Working Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcvgxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I've replaced

```
mat-tab-group fxFill>
```

into

```
<mat-tab-group style="height: calc(100% - 64px); min-height: calc(100% - 64px); min-width: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px;">
```

Comment: your "working link" no longer works, can you update this?

Comment: Adding height:100% to mat-tab-group is enough.

Comment: Yes it works. Thx lots @Liviu Nita